# CORS header allow origin error when loading image via JavaScript

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I believe I have done everything correctly to set a CORS header for images stored in firebase storage but I'm getting an error when I attempt to access it with my code.

My cors.json file looks like this:

```
[ 
{ 
"origin": [ 
"http://localhost:9090", "https://xrd.github.com" 
], 
"responseHeader": [ 
"Content-Type" 
], 
"method": [ 
"GET", 
"HEAD", 
"DELETE" 
], 
"maxAgeSeconds": 3600 
} 
]
```

I ran this command:

```
$ gsutil cors set cors.json gs://yumejs-42402.appspot.com
```

Can I validate things work properly with a cURL command? I should see the header in any request right?

```
$ curl -Is 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yumejs-42402.appspot.com/o/images%2FT7inLHFI8CPZNFYB9LMla2rkKHh1%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=3174a842-42fd-4155-8948-1f07f8ba10b6' \ 
| grep Access | grep Origin


Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This means it is not correct, right? This seems like it would permit all requests...

Can I review the CORS settings inside the Firebase web console (or in cloud.google.com)?

This link documents the issue (you'll need to look at the JS console)

https://xrd.github.io/yume.js/player.html?comic=W3sibW9kZWxzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9maXJlYmFzZXN0b3JhZ2UuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vdjAvYi95dW1lanMtNDI0MDIuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vby9pbWFnZXMlMkZUN2luTEhGSThDUFpORllCOUxNbGEycmtLSGgxJTJGMS5qcGc/YWx0PW1lZGlhJnRva2VuPTMxNzRhODQyLTQyZmQtNDE1NS04OTQ4LTFmMDdmOGJhMTBiNiIsInR5cGUiOiJpbWFnZSJ9XSwiZHVyYXRpb24iOjUsImV4cGFuZGVkIjp0cnVlLCIkJGhhc2hLZXkiOiJvYmplY3Q6NiJ9XQ==

The error printed inside the JS console is:

> "Access to Image at
>   'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yumejs-42402.appspot.com/o/imag…B9LMla2rkKHh1%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=3174a842-42fd-4155-8948-1f07f8ba10b6'
>   from origin 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. Origin 'https://xrd.github.io' is therefore
>   not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using github.com inside my cors.json, and the site from which the image was referenced was github.io.